# application of stone weierstrass theorem1

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that the function $f:[0,\infty)\Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous bounded function. Then $f$ is identically equal to zero if $\int_0^\infty f(x)\exp(-nx)=0$ for all $n=1,2,\cdots$.

Comment: You should add some of your thoughts, what you've tried, context, ...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Make the change of variables $x= -\ln u.$ Then the condition is that

$$\int_0^1 f(-\ln u)\cdot u^n\cdot (1/u)\,du = 0,\, n = 1,2,\dots,$$

which implies $\int_0^1 f(-\ln u)\cdot u^n\,du = 0, n = 0,1,\dots.$ This in turn implies $\int_0^1 f(-\ln u)p(u)\,du = 0$ for every polynomial $p.$

Comment: You don't actually need $p(0)=0$, just remember to multiply the integrand with the Jacobian. Additional hint: You can assume that $f$ vanishes af infinity by replacing $f(x)$ with $f(x)e^{-x}$.

Comment: Right, I forgot the Jacobian! Thank you. We don't need to worry about the vanishing until at the end, where we can approximate $u f(-\ln u)$ by polynomials. (We could also use the fact that polynomials are dense in L^2.)